# Can Flask (Python) be ported to Lua?

Tags: python, web-applications, web, lua, flask

Is there anything **[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)** (the Python webframework) does that **[Lua](http://www.lua.org/)** as a language doesn't support?

I'd like to re-implement Flask, which is developed in Python, over to Lua to create a new Lua webframework similar to Flask. But before I attempt to create a new Lua webframework, based on Flask as a reference, I'd like to know from the start if certain features Flask provides won't transition over to Lua because of the differences between Python and Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any language features you'd be missing in Lua that may prevent you from implementing something similar to Flask.

I'm sure you checked this already, but just in case: there are several webframeworks already available for Lua, some under active development (and some haven't been updated for a while):

- [Orbit](http://keplerproject.github.io/orbit/)
- [Flea](https://github.com/mikejsavage/flea)
- [Lapis](http://leafo.net/lapis/) (Lua and Moonscript)
- [Tir](http://tir.mongrel2.org/)
- [LuaMVC](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/LuaMVC/)
- [Webylene](https://github.com/slact/webylene-lua)
- [Mercury](https://github.com/nrk/mercury)

Comment: Moonscript is Lua. It's a DSL of Lua to resemble CoffeeScript

Comment: @nickb, Leaf indicated Lua examples are on the todo list; all the current ones are for Moonscript.

Comment: The Lua version has been released, http://leafo.net/lapis/#lang=lua, I haven't translated all of the reference manual yet but you can find a detailed example here http://leafo.net/lapis/reference.html#lapis-in-lua